# m2e-android and eclipse kepler/adt latest: apklib classes and resources not included in final apk

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, apklib

Anyone got any idea why that could be? I did "properties -> android -> add lib" and also added the apklib project to the build path. It is also imported to the workspace and opened and built. it really drives me nuts because the v7 support libs are included in the final apk as desired, but not my own apklib project. All of the projects show just fine in eclipse, only the final apk is cimpletely missing the apklib contents.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was a mis-configuration of the library's output folders: I had to set it for the source and resource files to the project default. For the resources, I also had to remove the ** default exclusion filter.